# Jelastic API Postman Collection?f

Tags: postman, jelastic, postman-collection

So I am starting to experiment with the Jelastic Cloud API, so far so good. I was in the process of building a set of Postman API calls for a Collection for my team, then it hit me...  Someone must have already created a collection for the Jelastic API. If you have, I would love to have a reference for the sake of saving a ton of time.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you elaborate why you're looking to create a Postman Collection? Is it just to have better sample request / responses than provided within the docs, or are there additional benefits?

Comment: Hey Damien, Yes, there are additional benefits. Prior to implementing systems programmatically, it is very helpful to explore and test the API's to get a better understanding of how they work and the return data that comes back. Having the api's implemented as a Collection means you can start from 0 knowledge to have a working understanding in minutes. Yes the API's are needed and super helpful, but having a quick to start sandbox is worth gold. =)

Comment: Understood. Making the API easier to explore and understand is something we're asking of the developers, so your question may inspire more progress towards that. In the meantime, if you're going ahead with building a Collection it would be great to share it as a github gist or similar?

Answer (score 0):

@jacobfogg, Jelastic has a good documentation according to your question:

- Jelastic [API Overview](http://docs.jelastic.com/api-overview)
- Jelastic [API Methods](http://docs.jelastic.com/api/)

Also, since the Jelastic version 4.0 you can use the [Jelastic command-line interface](http://docs.jelastic.com/cli-client) (CLI) client to executing the appropriate commands directly from your local machine. It allows to handle the vast majority of available operations remotely, complementing the wide stack of capabilities, provided via the dashboard and Jelastic API.

Comment: That documentation is how I am currently working through the API. Postman allows you to create and save all of the API endpoints as a "Collection". I can build out the collection, but I'd hate to duplicate all of that work if it is not needed.

Comment: As I see, Jelastic has a new post in his blog "[Easy and Powerful Way of Cloud Management via API](http://blog.jelastic.com/2015/11/17/jelastic-cli-easy-and-powerful-way-of-cloud-management-via-api/)".
This post can give you some basic knowledge of [Jelastic CLI](http://docs.jelastic.com/cli). This can be a good start to test it out and find the benefits for your particular project development.